# Find the biggest of two pytorch tensor on size

Tags: pytorch

How to find the biggest of two pytorch tensors on size

```
>>> tensor1 = torch.empty(0)
>>> tensor2 = torch.empty(1)
>>> tensor1
tensor([])
>>> tensor2
tensor([5.9555e-34])
```

torch.maximum is returrning the empty tensor as the biggest tensor

```
>>> torch.maximum(tensor1,tensor2)
tensor([])
```

Is there a way to find the biggest tensor among two tensors (mostly 1d), base on the number of elements in the tensor.

Comment: torch.maximum compute the elementwise maximum between 2 tensors which suggests they have the same number of elements. here even if  you compare torch.maximum(torch.empty(0), 100*torch.ones(1)) you still have the same result...
is this example relevant to your case ?

Comment: yes, sorry my mistake

Answer (score 1):

Why not comparing their first dimension size? To do so you can use equivalents: `x.size(0)`, `x.shape[0]`, and `len(x)`. To return the tensor with longest size, you can use the built-in [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) function with the `key` argument:

```
>>> max((tensor1, tensor2), key=len)
```

Comment: `'>' not supported between instances of 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'tuple' ` and `Boolean value of Tensor with no values is ambiguous`
'

Comment: Can you provide the types of `tensor1` and `tensor2`?

Comment: 1 d pytorch tensor, with float values.

Comment: Apologies, you must provide `len` as a keyword argument `key`, not a positional argument. See edit above.